# Rails 500 error showing blank page for PUT request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have setup custom error pages in my rails app.

**application.rb**

`config.exceptions_app = self.routes`

**routes.rb**

```
  get '404', to: 'application#page_not_found'
  get '422', to: 'application#server_error'
  get '500', to: 'application#server_error'
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
  def page_not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found_error', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all  { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def server_error
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/internal_server_error', layout: 'layouts/error', status: 500 }
      format.all  { render nothing: true, status: 500}
    end
  end
```

My custom 500 error page shows up fine when I do a GET request that throws the error but when I submit a form that triggers a NoMethodError, so a PUT request, I just get a blank page.

Any ideas why the 500 error page displays correctly for a GET request but not for a PUT request?

I tried changing the `server_error` method to

```
  def server_error
    render template: 'errors/internal_server_error', layout: 'layouts/error', status: 500 
  end
```

but this didn't seem to help.

Let me know if I can provide more code, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Try changing `get` to `match`.

Comment: In routes `get` means GET request, as `put`, `post`, `patch` and `delete` would. As @sa77 answered, try using match with `via: :all` instead.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped and close the question so people with similar problem can find it easily

Comment: @sa77 I will gladly accept. Do you care to comment on my question about `match` being deprecated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `match` and `via` on your routes.rb to route all types of HTTP requests to custom error actions

```
  # error routes
  match '/404' => 'application#page_not_found', :via => :all
  match '/422' => 'application#unprocessable_entity', :via => :all
  match '/500' => 'application#server_error', :via => :all
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I thought `match` was deprecated though. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964

Comment: some of the use cases of match is depreciated like using specific http verbs like `match :via => :get`, using generic routes `match '/:controller/:action'`, etc. You need to browse through rails gem's codebase  to investigate furthur `bundle open rails`. However, you will not get DEPRECIATION warning for using `match :via => :all`.